# Regular expression works in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-chrome, firefox

I have regular expression that checks for the file name. So far works fine in Firefox but when I tested in Chrome my regular expression was triggering if statement with the file that is properly named. Here is my regex:

```
if(!/^[a-z0-9_.@() -]+\.[^.]+$/i.test(fileName)){
    alert("Your file name has an invalid character.");
}
```

Alert should show up only if file has invalid name. Like I said this file `my test.txt` works in Firefox but in chrome alert was triggered. If anyone know why this would happen please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How are you populating the file name?

Comment: `var fileName = "my test.txt";` then `!/^[a-z0-9_.@() -]+\.[^.]+$/i.test(fileName)` in Chrome's console shows `false` for the latter as expected. Something *else* is going on, something not shown in the question; the regular expression isn't the problem.

Comment: I'm grabbing the file from the input type="file". This is my upload button value.

Comment: Try logging the file name just before the `if` condition to see if it is somehow different between the two browsers.

Comment: `/^[a-z0-9_.@() -]+\.[^.]+$/i.test('test.txt')` outputs *true* in a Chrome console.

Comment: That's the problem, Firefox is taking just the file name vs Chrome is garbing entire file path. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: `/^[a-z0-9_.@() -]+\.[^.]+$/i.test('test.txt')` also outputs `true` in the Firefox console, so I don't think the regex is your problem. If, like you said, Firefox is grabbing just the filename (by which I assume you mean just `test`), you need to provide more information about how where `fileName` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

So I found solution for my problem. I had to remove everything but the file name. I used this code:

```
var fileName = $('#fileUpload').val().split('\\').pop();
```

This will produce: `my test.txt`, if I did not use `.split('\\').pop()` my file anme would look like this: `C:\fakepath\my test.txt`

Comment: I think you might run into problems on different operating systems that use forward slashes in their file paths (e.g. ~/fakepath/my test.txt)

Comment: In what system/browser specifically?

Comment: The example I gave would be a pretty normal filepath in most Linux systems. I'm not super confident about Apple but I think they use forward slashes as well.